# Monotone likelihood ratio of densities based on power function

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, convex-analysis

Given $p,\phi,\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $p>2$ and $0 \le \phi,\theta\le \pi/2$ define the density function:

$$f(\phi;\theta) = 
\mbox{$\Large\frac{1}{p B\big(\hspace{-1pt}\frac{3}{2},\frac{p+1}{2}\hspace{-1pt}\big)}$}\Big(|\cos(\phi-\theta)|^p - |\cos(\phi+\theta)|^p \Big)\hspace{0.5pt} \frac{\sin(2\phi)}{\sin(2\theta)}$$

Show that $f(\phi;\theta)$ has a monotone likelihood ratio. I.e., for $0\le\theta_1 < \theta_2\le\pi/2$, the function:

$$ h(\phi) = \frac{|\cos(\phi-\theta_2)|^p - |\cos(\phi+\theta_2)|^p }{|\cos(\phi-\theta_1)|^p - |\cos(\phi+\theta_1)|^p }$$

is increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$. Equivalently, show that:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\hspace{2pt} \log f(\phi;\theta) > 0,\quad 0 \le \phi,\theta\le \pi/2$$

For $1\le p < 2$, the likelihood ratio is decreasing, and the derivative inequality is reversed. But the second partial derivative is $-\infty$ for $\phi=\theta$, which I think will still imply the MLRP, just an infinite slope in the likelihood ratio at one point.

The answer can be for the $1 \le p \le 2$ or $p>2$ case.

This result is important to prove uniqueness of stable optima in the unmixing and deconvolution of linear mixtures of independent random variables with strongly sub- and super-gaussian densities, using variation diminishing property of MLR densities. The result can be proved for $p=4$ by simplifying the derivative expression. This corresponds to using kurtosis as the the cost function, and the uniqueness result is already known in this case. For $p=1$, the likelihood ratio is non-increasing, constant around $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi/2$.

Comment: Where does the question arise from?

Comment: @YCor I edited to add background. I had posted some conjectures about more general functions, but they weren't true. Now I just want to prove it at least for the power function.

Comment: I finished writing my answer to your most recent (?) question "Monotone likelihood ratio of a kernel base on Huber loss function" two minutes after you deleted it. Can you restore it, so that my work not be wasted? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I realized that it was not true, that's why I deleted it.

Comment: @IosifPinelis If you post you answer I will accept it. I do believe that the other question on $\log(\cosh)$ is true. I also think $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ probably works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conjecture is true.

Indeed, we have to show that for $x$ and $t$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ we have
\begin{equation}
    h_2(p;x,t):=\partial_x\partial_t\,\ln(|\cos(x-t)|^p-|\cos(x+t)|^p)
\end{equation}
is $\ge0$ if $p\ge2$ and $\le0$ if $p\in(1,2]$.
(Note that for all $x$ and $t$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ we have $\cos^2(x-t)-\cos^2(x+t)=\sin2x\,\sin2t>0$, so that $h_2(g;x,t)$ is well defined.)

Note that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&   h_2(p;x,t)\frac{u^2 v^2}p\,(|\cos(x-t)|^p-|\cos(x+t)|^p)^2 \\ 
&   =H(p,u,v):=(p-1) u^{p+2} v^p-v^2 u^{2 p}-(p-1) u^p v^{p+2}+u^2 v^{2 p} \\ 
&   =s^2 v^{2 + 2 p} G(r,s),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    G(r,s):=(r+1) s^{r+2}-s^{2 r+2}-(r+1) s^r+1, 
\end{equation}
$u:=|\cos(x+t)|$, $v:=|\cos(x-t)|$, $s:=u/v$, and $r:=p-2$, so that $0<u<v\le1$, $s\in(0,1)$, $r\in(-1,0]$ when $p\in(1,2]$ and $r\ge0$ when $p\ge2$.

So, it suffices to prove that, for $s\in(0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
    G(r,s)
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
\overset{\text{(?)}}\le0&\text{ if }r\in(-1,0], \\      
\overset{\text{(?)}}\ge0&\text{ if }r\ge0.      
\end{aligned}
\right.
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation}

To prove this, let
\begin{equation}
    G_1(r,s):=\frac{\partial_s G(r,s)}{(1 + r) s^{r-1}}
    =r (s^2-1)-2 s^2 (s^r-1). 
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
    G_2(r,s):=\partial_r G_1(r,s)=-2 s^{r+2} \ln s+s^2-1,
\end{equation}
which clearly decreases in real $r$ for each $s$ ($s\in(0,1)$).  So,
\begin{equation}
    G_2(r,s)\le G_2(-1,s)=-2 s \ln s+s^2-1=:q(s). 
\end{equation}
We have $q(1)=0=q'(1)$ and $q''(s)=2-2/s<0$ (as $s\in(0,1)$). So, $q<0$ in $(0,1)$ and hence $G_2(r,s)<0$ (for the relevant $r,s$). So, $G_1(r,s)$ is decreasing in $r$. Also, $G_1(0,s)=0$. So, $G_1(r,s)>0$ for $r\in(-1,0)$ and $G_1(r,s)<0$ for $r>0$.

So, $G(r,s)$ is increasing in $s\in(0,1)$ for each $r\in(-1,0)$ and $G(r,s)$ is decreasing in $s\in(0,1)$ for each $r>0$. Also, $G(r,1)=0$.

Thus, \eqref{10} follows. $\quad\Box$

---

Below are the symbolic calculations, in Mathematica, of $H(p,u,v)$, $G(r,s)$, $G_1(r,s)$, $G_2(r,s)$, $q(s),q(1),q'(1),q''(s)$, $G_1(0,s)$, and $G(r,1)$:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for working on this.